# Array formula text join with column header

Tags: type-conversion, google-sheets-formula, textjoin, columnheader

How to fix this formula, so I can turn the column of dates into text?

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE((IF(row($A:$A)=1,"DATE LOOKUP",(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A))))))
```

This formula is combining all in one cell - I need each cell to convert in the column not all in one.

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE((IF(row($A:$A)=1,"DATE LOOKUP",(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A))))))
```

I need to know how to fix this formula so that the results look like this

[image]

Comment: Start by not SHOUTING at us in the title. Some on here skip questions like that.

Comment: it seems to me like this is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,(Y%20or%20Why%3F).) What is the use case of converting the dates to strings?

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also very impolite to shout at the people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**. Thanks.

Comment: @ken Sorry about the caps - 
How do I flag this query as solved?

Comment: How was it solved? If the answer you received solved it, you can say so by accepting it as correct by clicking the checkmark next to it (and upvote it as well, if you'd like). If you found the answer yourself and want to share it, write an answer in the space provided below for that purpose - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date Lookup";IF(A2:A<>"",TEXT(A2:A,"d-mmm-yyyy"),)})
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great.  Please consider marking this answer as solved.

Comment: Oi sorry how do I flag this as solved??? I tried looking around but could not find how to do it..

Comment: Should have a checkmark at the top left of the answer.  Click on the checkmark.

Comment: Aaaaaah ok I found it my bad thanx for the kind guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TO_TEXT:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(A2:A))
```

Comment: Thanx let me try

Comment: But I lost my header??

Comment: You can use A:A instead of A2:A